The poi output percentage is in progress bar format
I encountered a problem when exporting data as progress bar using poi, and a progress bar will be displayed when the value is 0%. I need your help to solve it, thank you.Here is my source code.
private void createProgressShape(Map<Integer, Double> map, Workbook workbook, Sheet sheet) {
    CellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
    cellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
    cellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
    cellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
    cellStyle.setTopBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
    cellStyle.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
    cellStyle.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
    cellStyle.setRightBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());

    DataFormat percent = workbook.createDataFormat();
    cellStyle.setDataFormat(percent.getFormat("0.00%"));

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer rowNum : map.keySet()) {
        Row row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
        Cell cell = row.getCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue(map.get(rowNum));
        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
        list.add(rowNum);
    }
    List<Integer> segmentEndpoints = getSegmentEndpoints(list);
    CellRangeAddress cra[] = {
            new CellRangeAddress(segmentEndpoints.get(0), segmentEndpoints.get(1), 1, 1),
            new CellRangeAddress(segmentEndpoints.get(2), segmentEndpoints.get(3), 1, 1)
    };
    XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(new byte[]{(byte) 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, (byte) 0xFF});
    SheetConditionalFormatting cf = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
    ConditionalFormattingRule cfRule = cf.createConditionalFormattingRule(color);
    cf.addConditionalFormatting(cra, cfRule);
    DataBarFormatting format = cfRule.getDataBarFormatting();
    format.getMinThreshold().setRangeType(ConditionalFormattingThreshold.RangeType.PERCENT);
    format.getMinThreshold().setValue(0d);
    format.getMaxThreshold().setRangeType(ConditionalFormattingThreshold.RangeType.PERCENT);
    format.getMaxThreshold().setValue(100d);
}

Below is the exported rendering.


Can you post also the getSegmentEndpoints method body? Maybe there's an issue in how is calculated the boundaries, since the issue is not just on the 0% cells, but also on the 100% (it is empty), and the others does not seem correctly shaped: it is like the percentage is calculated measuring both B and C column size, and not just the B one.

Only lines 3-12 and 16-17 of the second column were rendered

The use of CellRangeAddress determines the scope of the conditional format application, but it does not directly affect the display logic of the progress bar. The reason why a value of 0 also has a progress bar is usually determined by the conditional format or the logic of setting the progress bar, rather than by CellRangeAddress control.
